# How to create tablespace in DB2?

Tags: db2, tablespace

I want to create tablespace in DB2 and my platform is AIX.

I want to have that tablespace in a directory at my operating system. I have also created a bufferpool having the same pagesize of tablespace. But getting SQLCODE=-104.

```
CREATE BUFFERPOOL BPOOL  SIZE 2000 PAGESIZE 16K;

CREATE TABLESPACE TS01 

MANAGED BY DATABASE 
USING ( '/dbdata/UMPSYS01' )  
PAGESIZE 16K
BUFFERPOOL BPOOL
```

I have tried with `DEVICE` and `FILE` tokens giving the sizes too. But unable to run it.

Following error I am getting:

```
18:13:38  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=USING ( '/dbdata/UMPSYS01' );ESPACE TS01 
;<space>, DRIVER=3.61.75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very important (unforunately) that you get the syntax correct, with the keys in the right order.  The syntax diagram for the `CREATE TABLESPACE` statement is available [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000929.html).

You've put the `PAGESIZE` clause *after* the `MANAGED BY ...` which is incorrect.  It should be before:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE TS01 
    PAGESIZE 16K
    MANAGED BY DATABASE 
    USING (FILE '/dbdata/UMPSYS01.dms' 100M)  
    BUFFERPOOL BPOOL
```

Comment: Perfect. Is it necessary that the physical file in the directory have .dms extension? I was not giving it.

Comment: No, it's not necessary, I just use it as convention.